# long google drive video not playing

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, video-streaming, html5-video

I am having a issue that when I am trying to play google drive videos using html and JavaScript then only small videos play, like when I try to play longer videos they don't play, I think I have heard somewhere that video files longer than 25 mb can't be played because of virus issues. please let me know if there is any way I can play longer videos that are uploaded on google drive using html and JavaScript. Thank you

Comment: Google drive is a file storage system it is not a video hosting system.  Your should upload your video to YouTube if you want video hosting.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, can you please explain me how I can use 'YouTube video' in html through its link using video tag

Comment: Is there an example link of one video? It'll be easier to check what is wrong.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fi_1Rxdb9VcZXGaY87Lp_aEuPUN32T-m/view?usp=sharing